# What are the advantages and disadvantages of reprojecting a raster?

Tags: qgis, python, rasterio

When I reproject a raster with any software like QGIS, rioxarray, etc.

Can it generate problems or loss of information in the pixels?

For example:

If I want to reproject a raster from UTM coordinates to geographic coordinates.

Why reproject is a lossy process?

[image]

Is that normal?

[image]